# Проблема с кодировкой (Graphics)

Tags: c#

Надо при помощи Graphics нарисовать на Bitmap'e текст и сохранить его как файл (.png) С английским текстом всё нормально, а с русским нет. Вот код рисования:

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Bold);
foreach (var item in names)
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(250,100);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
    g.DrawString(ConvertUTF(item), font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
    g.Dispose();
    bm.Save(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item) + "1.png");
    progressBar1.Value += 100 / names.Count;
}
```

Код ConvertUTF:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
return enc.GetString(bytes);
```

И получаю это:
[image: ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Код ConvertUTF:

Удали эту ерунду и всё заработает.

Comment: Спасибо Большое!

Comment: Прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.